# Error in pushing modified local folder to github

Tags: git, github, git-push

I have a folder called Users/poudel/Copy/github/Astro.
i also have a repository called Astro in my github account.
in the Astro directory i gave follwing commands:

```
git add Astro
git commit -m "updated folder"
git push origin master
```

then it showed an error that one of the file exceed limit 100Mb.
so i delted that file and run above commands again.
but again it shows large file error even though i delted that file.

how can i upload the updated folder to the github website now?

Comment: You may want to .gitignore that file and move it manually between environments.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to push a file > 100MB, which github forbids.  You may find some help or suggestions [here](https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-large-files/), but github just doesn't allow single files of that size.

Comment: i have deleted the large file, and repeated same commands again but still it says i have large file.

Comment: Do you have a commit in your local history that contains the large file?  remember that you're not just pushing the HEAD commit, you're pushing the entire history difference between the remote and your local clone.  If you do have a commit with a large file, you might want to look into doing an interactive rebase with `git rebase -i ...` and editing the commit to remove the file.